# Creating a parameterless property attribute c#

Tags: c#, custom-attributes

I'm trying to create an attribute which reads a string property, does some work and replaces it.

How can i access the property from the attribute?

Attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class CustomAttribute : Attribute
{
    public CustomAttribute()
    {
        //get the property value
        //propertyValue = propertyValue + "!";
        //set the property value to be the updated propertyValue;

        //how do i get the value of the property the attribute is added to and modify it?
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
[CustomAttribute]
public string MyProperty { get; set; }
```

Comment: Attributes themselves are markers. On their own they do nothing until they are called by something. Also don't define any "custom processing" in the constructor. Instead create a method that can be called on the attribute or handle the processing by something else that uses the attribute as metadata. There are examples out there as well as frameworks like Autofac that provide the ability to introduce AOP into your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attributes don't *do* anything. They are metadata - they aren't active unless you *query the metadata* for the attribute model, or you're using certain IL rewriting tools. Note that an attribute doesn't have direct access to the context upon which it resides - for that, you'd need to add methods to your attribute, and invoke those methods on the materialized attribute, *passing in* any required context.

An object instance of an attribute is only created when *you ask for that* via the reflection APIs (and: it gives you an entirely different instance every time you query). Until then, it *just* exists as metadata.

Comment: Ok thanks, would you suggest using an ActionFilterAttribute instead?

Comment: @SamJones that depends *entirely* on the context; for example, you didn't mention MVC anywhere... and note: action filters are still passive like above - just, the MVC framework itself does the "materialize and execute known methods" step

Comment: Thanks, i'll go back and research